# Unauthorized Microsoft Graph API Add member in group

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I am using Microsoft Graph API in my SPFx website. I can successfully get `accessToken` using ADAL.js. I can create user, get users, get groups but when i am trying to add members in group it throws error of Unauthorized.

I had assiged full permission to app resource and my signed in user is global administrator.

With graph explorer same request is working fine.

All parameters value passes are true that I have verified.

```
private AddUserInGroup(httpClient: HttpClient, accessToken: string, objUser: IUser, groupId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (isAdded: boolean) => string, reject: (error: string) => string): void => {
        httpClient.post("/groups/" + groupId + "/members/$ref", HttpClient.configurations.v1, {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            },
            body: "{ \"@odata.id\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + objUser.id + "\"}"
        })
        .then((response: HttpClientResponse): void => {
            debugger;
            if (response.ok)
            resolve(true);
            else
            reject(response.statusText);
        }), (error: any): void => {
            debugger;
            alert(error.message);
            if (error.message.toLowerCase() == "failed to fetch")
            resolve(true);
            else {
                alert("Error : " + error.message);
                reject(error.message);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

If anyone knows answer then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you take the code from? If it's not your original piece of art, you **need** to add a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
httpClient.post("/groups/" + groupId + "/members/$ref", HttpClient.configurations.v1, {
```

Post Url goes wrong. It takes SharePoint site url. So we have to write full url to call instead of starting `/groups`